# flutter, How to judge whether another widget is in the tree

Tags: flutter

Actually, I have a parent widget, and It has some of the child widgets in its Column.
like this

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  color: Colors.white,
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 50.0, 20.0, 0.0),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
        Title(),
        SizedBox(height: 80.0,),
        confirmLoginType(),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        LoginButton(),
        PolicyTips(
           key: IndexGlobalKey.policyTipsKey,
           updateState: receiveMessageUpdateState
        ),
        Bottom()
     ],
   ),
),
```

in the `PolicyTips`, I pass a key to it, and I want to get the key in the `LoginButton` , but It has always been `null` when I get `currentState`.

- The code is below:`LoginButton`

```
class LoginButton extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginButton({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginButtonState createState() => _LoginButtonState();
}

class _LoginButtonState extends State<LoginButton> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    policyTipsKey = IndexGlobalKey.policyTipsKey.currentState;
    return Container(
        child: Text()
    )
  }
}
```

what can I do? help me please, thanks.

- This is `IndexGlobalKey` code.

```
class IndexGlobalKey {
    static final GlobalKey<_PolicyTipsState> policyTipsKey = GlobalKey<_PolicyTipsState>();
    static GlobalKey<_FormState> phoneLoginKey = GlobalKey<_FormState>();
    static GlobalKey<_FormForIdCardLoginState> idCardLoginKey = GlobalKey<_FormForIdCardLoginState>();
}
```

Comment: definitely, ```PolicyTips``` is a stateFulWidget.

Comment: Hi! Your code looks ok, I think the problem is in `IndexGlobalKey.policyTipsKey`. Could you provide code? How do you declare this key?

Comment: Hi, @Mol0ko , Thank you for your help. I have edited my question and added `IndexGlobalKeyIndexGlobalKey` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build method of `_LoginButtonState` runs before `PolicyTips` renders and before `IndexGlobalKey.policyTipsKey` is actually set. The reason is `LoginButton` goes before `PolicyTips` in column. Thats why you get `null` when you call `IndexGlobalKey.policyTipsKey.currentState` from build of `_LoginButtonState`.

To solve this you need to call `IndexGlobalKey.policyTipsKey.state` right where you use it. For example, when you need to get policy tips state on button tap just use it inside `onPressed` callback:

```dart
class _LoginButtonState extends State<LoginButton> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // An example of your button
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        final policyTipsState = IndexGlobalKey.policyTipsKey.currentState;
        // Here you can use policyTipsState
      },
      child: Text('button'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I understood, but my scene is to get `policyTipsKey ` when the page initializes. can I get the `policyTipsKey` when the page initialized? or, How to watch whether the widget is attached `key` informing the message to `LoginButton `

Comment: In your case you can't get state of `policyTipsKey` inside LoginButtons build method.
Could you explain what exactly data you need to use from `_PolicyTipsState` inside `LoginButton`? I suppose you don't need to use keys here

Comment: I thought about it. I literally needn't get `policyTipsKey ` at initialization. thank you very much.